# Delete commits with same datestamp

Tags: git, rebase

As a result of a rebase error, I have lot of duplicate commits.

How can I delete the commits that have the same datestamp of another commit?

I want to delete the duplicates without performing any change to the other commits, to preserve the history as it was before.

I already tried to do it manually with `git rebase`, by dropping them, but it didn't work.

Comment: I think it would help to show a before and after of what you're wishing to do. Note you can't just remove commits without changing the commit IDs of every commit after it. You might benefit from just starting the rebase over and doing it properly, and then bringing in your new commits that you did after it into your new, fixed, branch.

Comment: The duplicates might not matter. Rebase _does_ duplicate commits; that's how it works. But the duplicates will eventually be deleted automatically, so there might be no issue here.

Comment: As matt explained, rebase works by duplicating commits. Just make sure there is no branch at the top of the commit chain you want to disappear, and they will eventually get garbage collected.

Comment: Based on the last two comments, which have interpreted this question differently than I did, I think further clarification of the problem would be helpful. I think those two comments are assuming you mean duplicate commits in your reflog, which is normal when rebasing. My interpretation is based on "a rebase **error**", which implies that you have duplicate commits on your branch- either multiples on the same branch, or duplicates of commits already present on a shared branch, meaning you will have multiple copies on the shared branch when you merge your branch in.

Comment: if your intention is to "return to the way things were before", run `git reflog <branchname>` (or `git reflog`) and search for the state of your branch before the rebase. You can `git log --oneline --graph <sha>` to check how the history of a commit looks like, and use `git reset <sha>` to return to a specific commit.

Comment: @LeGEC Thank you, I solved the issue in this way.

In addition, my issue wasn't related with the normal rebase dublicated commits. There were some extra duplicated commits, I presume because I messed up something,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to "return to the way things were before", check your reflog:

run `git reflog <branchname>` (or `git reflog`) and search for the state of your branch before the rebase.

You can check the history of a given commit you see in the reflog:

```
git log --oneline --graph <sha>
```

Once you have spotted the commit you want to return to, use `git reset <sha>` to restore your branch to that state.
If you have no local changes you want to save, you may use `git reset --hard <sha>` -- caution: `git reset --hard` will delete from your disk modifications that are not stored in git, so such changes can be deleted without any way to recover them through git. use with care, check your `git status` before using it, and make sure that the modifications you want to keep are somehow already saved (stashed or committed).